# Empirical Evidence of Cournot Competition?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand, competition

Is there empirical evidence to validate the use of Cournot competition between multiple suppliers and a buyer?

Are there models which extend Cournot competition to different levels in a larger supply chain? Is there evidence to show that firms at the same level in a supply chain, be it at different levels, compete a la Cournot?